# Input text not working on Cordova

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, web-applications, cordova-3

I'm writing a WebApp for Android using Cordova 3.5

When i compile and run my application, all the input text's don't work, i try to input some text but no work.

I try to do some CSS tricks like `*{user-select: text;}`, but also don't work.

I build my app using jQuery mobile 1.4.3

Someone knows what's happening?

Comment: Need more code. How have you declared the inputs , how are you retrieving them etc. etc. Does button click works!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete position:absolute from the CSS of container